# How to get records only for this week with timestamp in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, timestamp

I have a Table in Database which has records of Logins.

```
    Table name: user_logins
    ID | timestamp
    1    2019.01.03  (Year, Month, Day)
    2    2019.01.04
    3    2019.01.05
    4    2019.01.05
    5    2019.01.07
    6    2019.01.07
    7    2019.01.09
```

I want to Show only Count of Records by this Week.
From Monday to Sunday (04-02-2019 ... 10-02-2019)

My PHP and SQL Code is:

```
    $mo = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user_logins WHERE DAYNAME(DATE(timestamp)) = "monday" and timestamp >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-0 DAY)'));
```

this should show the records of 04-02-2019

Here is my SQL Fiddle link:
[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pD46YHwrMdm8oRnhpxRgnc/1)

Comment: Note that using an archaic, insecure, and deprecated API is ill-advised,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)
```

gives this week's Monday. 
So:

```
SELECT * FROM user_logins 
WHERE
timestamp 
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)
and
NOW()
```

Comment: How can I set it to show the records of tuesday, wednesday ... and Sunday?

Comment: This code shows all the rows of the current week up to today.

Comment: Found it with: 

`SELECT * FROM user_logins 
WHERE
timestamp 
BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)
and
NOW() and DAYNAME(DATE(timestamp)) = "sunday"`

Comment: This code applies only to the current week starting on Monday.

Comment: Oki, can we Code an other Code and get the Records of montly? :)

Comment: Use this: `select * from user_logins where month(timestamp) = month(current_date()) and year(timestamp) = year(current_date())` to get the rows of the current month.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
 SELECT id FROM `user_logins`
    WHERE timestamp >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
    AND timestamp < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dUSzyGc6SaXbQzYizpAMA4/0)

Comment: Have tried it but it doesnt shows the records of this day: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pD46YHwrMdm8oRnhpxRgnc/2

Comment: you need to remove `dayname()` condition. It's not required in my opinion.